# os.walk giving non existent directories

Tags: python

I have a folder in which there are subfolders corresponding to 10 different classes, and the names of these subfolders are my labels. I came up with the following code to read the images into a Numpy array and save the labels.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import glob
import os

x=np.empty([28,28])
y=np.empty([1,0])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("filepath"):
    for roots in root:
        os.chdir(roots)
        images = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(roots+"/*.jpg")])
        num_of_images=images.shape[0]
        if num_of_images == 0:
            continue
        else:
            x = np.concatenate((x,images),axis=0)
            labels = np.empty([num_of_images,1])
            labels = labels.astype(str)
            #labels = get from last part of file name in roots
            #y=np.concatenate((y,labels),axis=0)
```

The error I'm getting is

> os.chdir(roots)
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'U'

When I `print(root)` it gives the correct subfolder paths. How do I handle this error?

EDIT : 
Got it working by removing `for roots in root` since os.walk returns a 3 tuple for each directory where root gives us the directory paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root` will be a string; the name of the current directory of `os.walk`.

```
for roots in root:
```

will iterate over that string; `roots` will iterate over `root` one character at the time... `os.chdir(some character)` will not work.

Comment: Ah. So I should use dirs instead?

Comment: i suggest you print out `root, dirs, files` so see what they are and then proceed with what you need. i'm not sure calling `os.chdir` while iterating over `os.walk` will work as expected...

Answer (score 1):

As [docs on os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) say, first item in each 3-tuple it returns is a string.
As such, `for roots in root:` iterates over characters of the string.
You need to read carefully what kind of data structure `os.walk()` returns and restructure your script accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Others already pointed out what is wrong, so I will not repeat it.
I'll just add that you should use

```
help(os.walk)
```

or whatever function isn't working as you expect it to, inside the interpreter before asking a question.

You handle this error as follows:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for thedir in dirs:
        p = os.path.join(root, thedir)
        os.chdir(p)
```